# Netbeans annoying yellow highlighting in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, netbeans-7.3

I am getting a yellow highlighting in javascript code when clicked inside of the code ,Its not the yellow highlighting of supposed bracket intent notation and warning ,any idea of what is that and how to get rid of that ?? I am posting the pic below ! [image]

Comment: Man, that's surely a minuscule screencap... Do you really expect people to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Syntax [Category : keywords] Select Foreground: black.

Added: Javascript embedded in html / php Syntax [ Language : HTML ] Select "Javascript Embedded in HTML" Select Background: inherited.

Comment: I think its under mark occurrences Backgroundcolor:yellow[236,235,165] , but where is the occurrence of code here ??

Answer (score 1):

I have not NetBeans currently installed, but, I think you should 
*Fonts and Colors > Syntax.  Choose Language:* 
And probably disable **Mark Occurences**

Comment: okay earlier answer worked too, but it was under Mark Occurences and i changed the color to inherited

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Okay good. Would you please click on ACCEPT ANSWER.

Comment: @Umair Your answer is ok. However, I want to be clearer with this process using Netbeans 8.0.2: choose the language, then, pick out Mark Ocurrences on Category list. There's no a checkbox to disable it, instead of that, we should change the [background color](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4re2165grasr3xa/netbeans_mark_ocurrences.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

This setting keeps moving around almost as much as Marco Polo. :)

For NetBeans 8.2, I found it at:
Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax > All Languages > Mark Occurrences

Change FG and BG colors to your liking.